# Which preposition is correct, "asset to", "asset for" or "asset of"?

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition would be grammatically correct?

> I am confident that I have the character and integrity to be an asset *to* your organization.
>
> I am confident that I have the character and integrity to be an asset *of* your organization.
>
> I am confident that I have the character and integrity to be an asset *for* your organization.

Comment: This will probably be moved to ELL as it is too "easy" for this site...I'd use *to*.

Answer (score 2):

An asset *to* an organization is something that adds value or is useful to the organization. So this is usually the phrase used in your context, often with the intensifier "real asset".

An asset *of* an organization is anything that belongs to the organization. This literally just refers to possessions (real estate, cash, office furniture and equipment, etc.). However it's often used figuratively to include employees -- many companies will say something like "Our employees are our biggest asset" to make it seem like they value employees strongly.

But since all employees are assets in the second sense, saying "I would be an asset of your organization" is simply a tautology. You'd need to say "an important asset" or "a critical asset" to emphasize that you wouldn't just be another cog in the machine.

Answer (score 0):

"to" is better than "of" and reads more naturally.

"To" makes sense here because you are making a relationship to the company, presenting yourself as an asset to them.

"Of" could imply the company would wield your asset as a tool of the company.